# Getting com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Read timed out)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting following exception. Can anyone give pointers about why is it coming?

```
 AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = AWSEC2Client.getAWSEC2Client(set basicCredentials :: accesskey and secret key);

 ec2Client.setRegion(set regions);

 final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration()
                .withConnectionTimeout(150000).withMaxConnections(200)
                .withRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(null, null, 3, true));

 describeInstancesResult = ec2Client.describeInstances(new DescribeInstancesRequest().withFilters(filterList));
```

> #011at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:5392) ~[aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    #011at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:11095) ~[aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    #011at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:311) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    #011at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:362) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    #011at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:400) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    #011at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:631) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    #011at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:893) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    #011at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1281) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]
>    com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Read timed out). Response Code: 200, Response Text: OK

Comment: Can I use withClientExecutionTimeout or .withRequestTimeout(requestTimeout) methods .If yes the what value should I use for testing .

Comment: Getting the same error, no idea about the root cause.